# Is there a fast way to detect drag events on a game object in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, input

Basically, I am designing a game where I need a canvas image element to respond quickly and move along when it is dragged. So for that, I am implementing *IDragHandler* interface. But the method *OnDrag* gets called after a delay of about half second.

```
public class InputHandler : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler
{
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        // this gets logged after about 500 milliseconds
        Debug.Log("mouse dragged");
    }
}
```

I've attached this script on the same image element that I want to move along with the drag. This element has raycast target on and the graphic raycast component is enabled for its parent canvas. The image element falls behind the touch point initially but catch up later on because of which it feels like there is some lag in the input. Is there a way to remove/minimize this delay?

Comment: Perhaps instead of drag you should look for touch? An OnPointerDown and OnDrag events maybe?

Comment: Also, i hope you realize that this function is only called if the pointer is on an UI element of a Canvas.

Comment: @Saif yes indeed, this script is attached on image element whose raycast target is on inside a canvas which has graphic raycast enabled and the image element is indeed moving with the drag but with some delay. Need to try out Touch though, seems like a lead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lag might be due to the DragThreshold that is active by default. You can disable it this way:

```
public class OnDragScript : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IInitializePotentialDragHandler
{
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData ped)
    {
        transform.Translate(ped.delta);
    }

    public void OnInitializePotentialDrag(PointerEventData ped)
    {
        ped.useDragThreshold = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Actually I set the drag threshold value to 0 in Event System component that Unity attaches automatically on adding canvas in the scene instead of implementing this interface. Before that this value was 20 (don't know how) and I was testing it on relatively low dpi device which was causing the said delay.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not finding any delay. Perhaps you should start with 3 functions (begin, drag and end) to find out what exactly is happening.
Also, the `IDragHandler` works only for canvas elements. So your pointer should be within the boundaries of UI element while you begin your drag.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class InputHandler : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnDrag");
    }

      public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Drag Begin");
    }

     public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        print("Drag End");        
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I am attaching the script in a canvas UI element and and dragging that object withing UI element boundaries using all three interfaces IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler. But still the 'Drag Begin' gets logged after some delay.

Comment: @Maxkiel sorry to hear that. I am not facing an issue here. Could you try this in a new project so that we can come to a conclusion whether it is in game problem or scripting.